# After upgrading Ubuntu 20.04, not able to access internet using firefox

Tags: 20.04, firefox

After upgrading Ubuntu 20.04, I am not able to access internet using Firefox on Dell Latitude laptop and Dell Optiplex 7010 desktop.

Comment: Is it just Firefox not connecting, but other apps/programs do( other browser,software update)?  If just Firefox would say some firefox setting is off.

Comment: Thank you.  I don't have apps that connect other than Firefox and Thunderbird but will download an alternative browser and run the upgrade again.

Comment: If you can download another browser or anything, then it is a problem in/with Firefox itself.  If you can't download then a network problem.  If network then we need to know if wired or wifi.  A reboot of Ubuntu and router probably won't hurt, might not help either.

Comment: Desktop is wired, laptop wireless.  Rebooted both machines and router and eventually reloaded Bionic Beaver from memory stick.  No problems then with Firefox or Thunderbird.  I will download another browser in this version, upgrade and see if that connects.

Comment: Did you use any proxy setting in Firefox that may be removed after upgrading to 20.04 ?